# mostrar y ocultar buttons

Tags: c#, windows-forms

necesito orientación para poder hacer lo siguiente, ya que no
 tengo idea como hacerlo en c# WinForms.

La actividad consta de de al
 darle seleccionar al checkbox de "`REPETIR`" se visualicen los botones
 de los dias de la semana y que al darle Activar cambien de color,
 cualquier orientación es buena, gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como mostrar/ocultar botones, soy nuevo en C#, necesito una pequeña guia para investigar por favor, agradeceria un codigo de ejemplo

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu problema. No sabes detectar cuando se pulsan los checkbox? No sabes como mostrar/ocultar los botones? no sabes como hacer que cambien de color? Edita tu pregunta y añade mas información, asi como que has intentado para resolverla

Comment: Los botones tienen una propiedad `.Visible`. Ponla a true/false y se mostraran/ocultaran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer consejo es que si son varios botones que deben actuar juntos los ubiques dentro de de otro control como ser un `GroupBox` o `Panel`.

Al estar todos juntos podras ocultarlo o mostrarlos de forma simple

```
private void chkRepetir_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    GroupBox1.Visible = chkRepetir.Checked;

}
```

asignas el mismo estado del checkbox asi se muestran si esta marcado ya que devuelve true o se oculta si esta desmarcado ya que tendra un false

[CheckBox.CheckedChanged Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: `private void roundedButtonGray1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1 = true)
            {
                roundedButtonGray1.Visible();
            }
            else
            {
                roundedButtonGray1.Hide();
            }`

Comment: Escribi ese codigo pensaba ponerlo en cada boton pero me marca error en el true, si se compara los booleanos con un solo = o cuantos, cual sera mi fallo

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' 


Pienso que debo convertirlo a booleano?

Comment: @alexdev no puedes poner `if (checkBox1 == true)`, debes comparar la propiedad `Checked`:  `if (checkBox1.Checked == true)`

Comment: Bien dicho @Pikoh pero me fallo la logica, eso hace que al presionar el boton el checkbox se haga true, intentare hacerlo recursivamente agregado el codigo al checkbox

Comment: @alexdev Lo que debes hacer es lo que te dijo Leandro. Simplemente iguala el valor de `Checked` con el de `Visible`: `roundedButtonGray1.Visible = chkRepetir.Checked;`

Comment: porque vas a poner ese evento en cada boton? se supone que visualizas los botones al presionar el checkbox, el evento es el del check no de los botones. No es el Click del boton sino el CheckedChanged para mostrarlos

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Maquina lo resolviste en una linea de codigo, funciona al a perfeccion, gracias. utilice el panel  y con  `panel1.Visible = checkBox1.Checked;`

y en el panel agregue 
`if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                panel1.Show();
            }
            else {
                panel1.Hide();
            }`

y funciona como queria, es un gran avance, gracias

Comment: no necesitas igualar a true en el if, con solo pones `if (checkBox1.Checked) {..` alcanza